# Google Places API to find all restaurants in UK

Tags: google-places-api

Google APis support specifying the `type` to search for - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/supported_types

Using Python or any other programatic language, is it possible to enumerate all the restaurants in entire UK? What kind of pricing costs will be incurred for using Google Places API to do this?

Thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is in part a customer service-related question. Contact Google Places customer service directly to ask about pricing for their  products. We cannot speak on the behalf of an off-site service or vendor. (It would be foolish to listen to some stranger on the internet, anyway. What would you do if you got a large bill or charge that you didn't expect? Complain that user87753 at SO told you it wouldn't cost you anything? Ask the vendor directly/.)

Answer (score 0):

Having to go down to a very fine zoom level in order approximately get most restaurants, you'd have two problems:

1. it's going to be HUGELY expensive
2. and more importantly: it's against their policies (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/policies):

> Pre-Fetching, Caching, or Storage of Content Applications using the
> Places API are bound by the Google Maps Platform Terms of Service.
> Section 3.2.3(a) and (b) of the terms states that you must not
> pre-fetch, index, store, or cache any Content except under the limited
> conditions stated in the terms.